# Can I choose which post will be next or previous post in blogger.com?

Tags: javascript, web, blogger, software-design

In blogger.com, Blog post generate automatically for next and previous post. I want to make a tutorials blog so I need to keep the next and previous post with a patterns. Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you want to customize the blog page order? Did you take a look at the [Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using)?

Comment: You could modify the `published` date to achieve this: [UI](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Post-Date-on-Blogger) or [API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#UpdatingAPost)